# CMS I am able to target the field I want to delete, but when I click on the edit button it does not target it any longer

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I made an application where you can create new exercises (for example as a teacher for your students), and whenever you add an extra field for your exercise it's all good and stuff, when you decide you made too many exercises for your students to make, you can click a delete function and it will delete the desired exercise field. However let's say you make an exercise and save it. In 2 months you come back and you want to delete from the 10 exercises 1. So you click the desired delete button. However it does not delete the targetted exercise field any longer. It deletes the first exercise field it can find instead of its parent exercisefield. This is how my delete function works:

```
function getRemoveBtnExercise(target, i){
  var RemoveExerciseBtn = $('<a/>', {
      'class': 'btn btn-danger'
   }).on('click', function(){  
   console.log($('.eblock').prop('id'))
        $('#' + target).remove();
   }).html('<i class="fa fa-close"></i>');

   return RemoveExerciseBtn;
}
```

how the eBlock looks like:

```
function getExerciseBlock(i, data){
  var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
    'id': i,
    'class': 'col-md-6 eBlock well'
  });

  data = data || {
    word: '',
    syllables: ['','','','']
  };

  $(eBlock).append(
    getRemoveBtnExercise(i),
    getAudioBtn(i),
    getWordInput(i, data.word),
    getWordPartInput(i, data.syllables)
    );

  return eBlock;
}
```

How the button has been made so you can edit the desired JSON file:

```
'<div class="btn-group">\
      <a href="exercise_CMS.php?id=' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-warning"> \
   <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> \
 </a> \
```

So to wrap it up: It DOES work when you decide to make a whole new exercise, however when you click on the "edit" button and add a new `eBlock` and THEN click to delete the `eBlock` you had just append (because you changed ur mind of adding a new `eBlock`) it all of the sudden loses this functionality...

Comment: It's difficult to understand without seeing an example. If it's deleting the first field it can find I would assume you're not targeting the right element to delete. It might be an issue with how you are targeting your elements, are you sure you're giving them a unique ID, and are you sure you're targeting them correctly on button press?

Comment: It does have an ID, i. it increments

Comment: Still think it's how you're targeting your element. Rather than passing through target as an ID it'd be better to pass through the event data from the button press. Then it'd be easier to target the element through the event data.

Comment: If `i` increments, I assume it's a number. Are you sure you're not using the same number for multiple elements? Anyways, it's really hard to test this code in any meaningful way, since we have no idea how the page is built/rebuilt every time a user visits it. We just see the code to create a button and code to create a eblock. But not how they are used inside the actual page.

Comment: The signature of your `getRemoveBtnExercise` function expects two parameters, but then you call it with `getRemoveBtnExercise(i)` - what’s up with that then?

Comment: The second parameter is never used, just as the eblock.prop(id) is never used. Already went over those issues. But we can't reproduce the issue without knowing how the jSON file gets transformed into the html eblocks again, since that's where the issue will be, inconsistent state management. The eblock and remove button code works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't add comments (I need 50 rep...) ! If you are adding the elements dynamically with JS then you need to add the listener everytime you add a new element. 
for example if I define an event listener :

```
$(".btn-danger").on('click', function(ev){...})
```

Then use jquery to add an element :

```
$("#container").append("<button class="btn btn-danger"> Delete </button>")
```

The onclick event will not be fired when clicked on the last added button, so we need to "rewrite" the event again :

```
 $(".btn-danger").on('click', function(ev){...})
```

In your case, I guess that you need to do the same after adding a new eBook.

Comment: I used the principle of what u had and it worked. thanks lol.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that !

Comment: @MabroukiFakhri - won't you be at risk of adding the same event listener multiple times to the existing dom elements if you're applying this to a class name? Or does jQuery ignore / overwrite existing click events?

Comment: When we use .click() a separate handler gets created for every single element that matches the selector.

When we use .on('click', ...)  a single handler for all elements that match your selector, including the ones created dynamically.